# Numpy elementwise product of 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I have two 3d arrays A and B with shape (N, 2, 2) that I would like to multiply element-wise according to the N-axis with a matrix product on each of the 2x2 matrix. With a loop implementation, it looks like

```
C[i] = dot(A[i], B[i])
```

Is there a way I could do this without using a loop? I've looked into tensordot, but haven't been able to get it to work. I think I might want something like `tensordot(a, b, axes=([1,2], [2,1]))` but that's giving me an NxN matrix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you are doing matrix-multiplications for each slice along the first axis. For the same, you can use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) like so -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',A,B)
```

We can also use [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) -

```
np.matmul(A,B)
```

On Python 3.x, this `matmul` operation simplifies with [`@` operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) -

```
A @ B
```

#### Benchmarking

Approaches -

```
def einsum_based(A,B):
    return np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',A,B)

def matmul_based(A,B):
    return np.matmul(A,B)

def forloop(A,B):
    N = A.shape[0]
    C = np.zeros((N,2,2))
    for i in range(N):
        C[i] = np.dot(A[i], B[i])
    return C
```

Timings -

```
In [44]: N = 10000
    ...: A = np.random.rand(N,2,2)
    ...: B = np.random.rand(N,2,2)

In [45]: %timeit einsum_based(A,B)
    ...: %timeit matmul_based(A,B)
    ...: %timeit forloop(A,B)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.08 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.04 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks Divakar. I wish I could use this, but I'm somewhat stuck with an older version of numpy that doesn't have einsum. Is there's a tensordot equivalent call?

Comment: I could never understand how `einsum` works.  Is there something you read up on that taught you how the syntax works?

Comment: @rayryeng Just the official docs and hours of playing around with it. There are still many other things I have seen people doing with it on SO that I need to figure out! Just play around with it, like you did with `permute`. Recently, figured out [how to use `np.einsum` to replace `np.any`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31824255/3293881), again by playing around with it.

Comment: @Remy Did you finally get access to `np.einsum` supported NumPy? I am  not really sure how to get tensordot to work in this case.

Comment: @Divakar Yeah I did on my own computer, and this really is so much faster that I'm gonna bite the IT bullet and upgrade everyone else's numpy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to perform the operation on the first dimension of your tensors, which is labeled by `0`:

```
c = tensordot(a, b, axes=(0,0))
```

This will work as you wish. Also you don't need a list of axes, because it's just along one dimension you're performing the operation. With `axes([1,2],[2,1])` you're cross multiplying the 2nd and 3rd dimensions. If you write it in index notation (Einstein summing convention) this corresponds to `c[i,j] = a[i,k,l]*b[j,k,l]`, thus you're contracting the indices you want to keep.

EDIT: Ok, the problem is that the tensor product of a two 3d object is a 6d object. Since contractions involve pairs of indices, there's no way you'll get a 3d object by a `tensordot` operation. The trick is to split your calculation in two: first you do the `tensordot` on the index to do the matrix operation and then you take a tensor diagonal in order to reduce your 4d object to 3d. In one command:

```
d = np.diagonal(np.tensordot(a,b,axes=()), axis1=0, axis2=2)
```

In tensor notation `d[i,j,k] = c[i,j,i,k] = a[i,j,l]*b[i,l,k]`.

Comment: I get a `(2, 2, 2, 2)` shape instead of `(10, 2, 2)` with your solution, so something may be wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you a wrong answer, please look at my EDIT.